# TypeScript: suppress Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

I came across with the following problem with TypeScript:

There is a module, which uses a function `myApp.common.anotherFunc()` from "old" js code :

```
module myApp {
    export module helpers {

        export class baseHelper {
            doWork() {
                var m = myApp.common.anotherFunc();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result typescript compiler shows an error "Property does not exist on type". How can I overcome this problem without rewriting my old functionality in `myApp.common` ?

P.S. TS version is 2.0 if it matters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare the function for the TypeScript:

```
declare module myApp.common {
    let anotherFunc: Function;
}

module myApp {
    export module helpers {

        export class baseHelper {
            doWork() {
                var m = myApp.common.anotherFunc();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This declaration does not generate any code and you won't see the compiler errors anymore because it knows about the function.

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly. But is it necessary to declare module another way if I got something like myApp.common["propA"]() ? Because in this case compiler exception still exists