# Typescript error: "[ts] Property 'existingProperty' does not exist on type '{}'."

Tags: typescript, react-native

Checked these links:

1. [Typescript error Property does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564922/typescript-error-property-does-not-exist-on-type)
2. [property then does not exist on type void , A typescript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428984/property-then-does-not-exist-on-type-void-a-typescript-error)
3. [Typescript property does not exist on type {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467069/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type)
4. [TypeScript: suppress Property does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649438/typescript-suppress-property-does-not-exist-on-type)
5. [TS2339: Property does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068806/ts2339-property-does-not-exist-on-type)
6. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1574

But I couldn't seem to understand this behavior.

### Reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/the-joat/rn-maps-ts-bug-demo
cd rn-maps-ts-bug-demo
yarn
yarn build
```

Typescript will successfully compile but I want to suppress the error you'll see in `Qwerty.tsx`.

I've tried having a `.d.ts` file that has:

```
import MapView from "react-native-maps"
declare module "react-native-maps" {
  const a: any
  export default a
}
```

but it's throwing another error and I don't think it's really a permanent solution since I won't be able to benefit from the types declared in `react-native-maps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the react and react-native type definitions are missing from the project. Those types are required to properly recognize the props of JSX elements. Try installing them:

```
yarn add --dev @types/react @types/react-native
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. For me, the problem was that I used:

```
<script lang="ts">
```

but, Composition API style.
The correct one should be:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
```

(The "setup" part was missing.)